# How to convert to good image quality in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can i receive image with good quality? After i got this code working, image size decreased but image quality was destroyed. Could you help me on this?

```
  foreach (var dir in new DirectoryInfo("F:\\little").GetDirectories())
  {
    if (!Directory.Exists($"F:\\Results\\{dir.Name}")) Directory.CreateDirectory($"F:\\Results\\{dir.Name}");

    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
      if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine($"F:\\Results\\{dir.Name}", file.Name)))
      {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "f:\\ffmpeg.exe", Arguments = $"-i {file.FullName} -q:v 10 {Path.Combine($"F:\\Results\\{dir.Name}", file.Name)}", WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden };
        process.Start();
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
  }
```

Comment: You're using q:v with a setting of 10. Try reducing that until you get acceptable quality. Somewhere between 2-5 should do nicely.

Comment: Thank you it works ı received good image quality with 2